# How do I make my nav bar collapsible with bootstrap for mobile devices?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

How do I make my nav bar collapsible with bootstrap for mobile devices? I've tried using the code directly from the bootstrap website but it either makes my nav bar completely disappear or it just doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my current nav bar.

```
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tarmac.html">Tarmac</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="paving.html">Paving</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the Navs Component, you have to use the Navbar component from Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

You can then copy/paste the code from the Navbar component and modify it to make your navbar, like this:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <!-- Start Navigation -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="tarmac.html">Tarmac</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="paving.html">Paving</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
        <!-- End Navigation  -->

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#how-it-works)...

> "Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with
> .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl} for responsive collapsing"

So follow the responsive navbar guidance [in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tarmac.html">Tarmac</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="paving.html">Paving</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```